# Counting separate occurrences in a string T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, ssms

I need help counting how many times a 'pattern' is found within a string. I'm using a tool which extracts inputted patters into a column. My dateset looks like the following:

| Id | MatchedPatterns |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "[Pattern One: SE09B00218], [Pattern Two: 0000000-09000,0974837-01]" |
| 2 | "[Pattern One: SE09B00218,DA02F11418], [Pattern Two: 0000000-09,0974837-01]" |
| 3 | "[Pattern One: TR38G01678,DA02F11418,KJ73F4567]" |
| 4 | "[Pattern Two: 0000009-00000007,1234567-02,0939485-0004,09836473-1]" |

You can see that each pattern can be found multiple times (up to 200), separated by a comma or it can be null. Each pattern identified can also be different lengths.

Here is what I want the output to look like:

| Id | PatternOneCount | PatternTwoCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 4 |

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't understand how you're arriving at your count values. What are you matching the patterns to? Your results don't make any sense.

Comment: It does, @Stu , for ID `1`, for example, you have the strings `Pattern One: SE09B00218`, and `Pattern Two: 0000000-09000,0974837-01`. `Pattern One` has one (delimited) value, while `Pattern Two` has 2 (`0000000-09000` and `0974837-01`).

Comment: I read it as finding the pattern within some other string data, but yes I see what the counts refer to now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're on a (fully) supported version of SQL Server, you could transform your data into valid JSON, and then consume it.

So first you `REPLACE` the brackets (`[]`) with double quotes (`"`), and the wrap the colons (`:`) with double quotes as well. Then you wrap the entire string in braces (`{}`), to get your JSON string.

Next you consume that JSON with `OPENJSON`, use `STRING_SPLIT` to split the delimited data, and then *finally* use conditional aggregation... *yuck*.

```sql
SELECT V.Id,
       COUNT(CASE J.[key] WHEN 'Pattern One' THEN SS.[value] END) AS PatternOne,
       COUNT(CASE J.[key] WHEN 'Pattern Two' THEN SS.[value] END) AS PatternTwo
FROM (VALUES(1,'[Pattern One: SE09B00218], [Pattern Two: 0000000-09000,0974837-01]'),
            (2,'[Pattern One: SE09B00218,DA02F11418], [Pattern Two: 0000000-09,0974837-01]'),
            (3,'[Pattern One: TR38G01678,DA02F11418,KJ73F4567]'),
            (4,'[Pattern Two: 0000009-00000007,1234567-02,0939485-0004,09836473-1]'))V(Id,MatchedPatterns)
     --Make the pattern valid JSON
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(V.MatchedPatterns,'[]','""'),': ','":"')))R(JsonPatterns)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('{',R.JsonPatterns,'}')) J
     OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(J.[value],',') SS
GROUP BY V.Id;
```

Comment: Thank you! But how would I apply this to the whole column instead of just the examples I've provided in the question? Thanks :-) @Larnu

Comment: It's already using all the rows in a column, @AdamCraven, the column `MatchedPatterns` so I don't follow what you're asking.

Comment: @Larnu Why the mystical `(fully)`? Are there partially supported versions?

Comment: Yes, those in Extended Support, @GeorgeMenoutis (Currently SQL Server 2012, 2014, and 2016). Only 2017 and 2019 are fully support (in Mainstream support).

Comment: @Larnu Interesting. On the documentation pages, when a feature is available in "all supported versions", I guess these include the extended ones, right?

Comment: They are still supported, @GeorgeMenoutis, just not *fully* supported. Versions in Extended Support don't get CU's/SP's any more  (which address bugs, performance issues, etc), they only get security fixes. Though they would also likely get a patch if a significant breaking issue was found (sort of like how 2008 was patched for spectre/meltdown even after it was completely unsupported as so many were still using it).